# How to prevent DataGrip to show results from another query console?

Tags: database, datagrip, database-tools

When I have multiple query consoles open in DataGrip, I usually make several queries to database simultaneously. One query console - one query. When I execute query to database and switch the query console before I get the result from database, I, for example, want to view results in another query console. I switch the query console, but then, after that query is complete, results are shown in query console I'm currently vieving, not the one, where I executed the query.
How to prevent DataGrip to do that?

Answer (score 1):

That is a usability problem and it's impossible right now. The workaround can be using 'In-editor' results in the second console:

[image]

Please, follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-12538

Comment: Hello @Moscas I noticed that the ticket has already been closed; yet the issue still remains. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried turning on the setting which is described in the last comment to the issue?